# Tailwind: combine 2 styles for text-decoration-line

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to a certain span of text to have both strike-throughs and underlines. This is possible in vanilla CSS like:

```
text-decoration-line: underline line-through;
```

I assumed with tailwind it would work similarly if I used the class like

```
class="underline line-through"
```

but it does not work. Only one of the styles apply at a time. Is there any way to get that behaviour with tailwind classes?

Comment: It's not ideal, but what about creating a custom class (with CSS utilities)?

Comment: yeah, that was my first though too. but it's not a very repeatable solution if I need to compose 2 different properties for a css style that usually can be combined. So I assumed tailwind would have some inbuilt way to handle it in general?

Answer (score 4):

Right now those `utilities` are not composable, you can either create your own `plugin`, or use `arbitrary properties` to achieve the result you want:

```
<div class="[text-decoration:underline_line-through]">hello</div>
```

Here is a quick playground link with the solution: https://play.tailwindcss.com/baW2CzoBur